# why is $\deg f(X) + \deg g(X) =\deg f(X)g(X)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that the ideal $\langle 2, X\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not principal

**My attempt** : I found the answer [here](https://people.math.carleton.ca/%7Ewilliams/ant/ch3-solns/ch3-qu5.pdf)

It is written that

> suppose  that the ideal $I=\langle2,X\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is principal.Then there  exist  $f(X)  \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $I=\langle f(X)\rangle$. As  $2 \in I$ there exist $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that  $2= f(X)g(X)$

> Hence  $\deg f(X) + \deg g(X) =\deg f(X)g(X) =\deg 2 =0$

**My confusion** : Im not getting why is  $\deg f(X) + \deg g(X) =\deg f(X)g(X)?$

**My thinking** :  I agree that $\deg f(X)g(X) =\deg 2$ is true.

But I don't agree with that $\deg f(X) + \deg g(X) =\deg f(X)g(X)$

because  $2 \neq f(x)  + g(x) \implies \deg 2 \neq \deg f + \deg g$

Comment: The degree of a product of polynomials is *always* the sum of the degrees of the two polynomials.

Comment: Have you worked out any examples  at all?  Multiply $f(x)=x^3+2$ and $g(x)=x^2-1$ and see what you get.

Comment: You're not supposed to agree with the conclusion, because it is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an integral domain $A$ and any two non-zero polynomials $f,g\in A[x]$ we have

$$\deg f(x)g(x)=\deg f(x)+\deg g(x),$$
Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$ and $g(x)=b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+b_0$, then what is the degree of their product $f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: okay  that means  $\deg (fg)=n+m =\deg f +\deg g$

Comment: Yes, $\deg(fg)=n+m=\deg f+\deg g$